# Python - ignore non-parsable strings

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

I have some strings in a text file that I'm parsing using `pandas`. A sample of it looks as below:

```
May 6, 2021 12:40:05 AM CEST INFO    [com.purge.PurgeManager run] PURGE: Purge all data beginning (1 threads)
May 6, 2021 9:12:17 AM CEST FINE    [com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientCall sendRequest] An error occured during the communication with the remote HTTP server.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ext.net.HttpUrlConnectionCall.getStatusCode(HttpUrlConnectionCall.java:299)
    at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientCall.sendRequest(HttpClientCall.java:173)
    at com.noelios.restlet.ext.net.HttpUrlConnectionCall.sendRequest(HttpUrlConnectionCall.java:183)
    at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientConverter.commit(HttpClientConverter.java:109)
    at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:88)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:120)
    at org.restlet.Uniform.handle(Uniform.java:106)
    at com.boomi.container.core.MessagePollerThread.run(MessagePollerThread.java:273)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Since the file has no column headers nor delimiters and dynamic width values, I'm using `str.strip()` to read line by line and then, to create a new file with column headers and comma delimited. Also, before writing into the output file, I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse` to convert the date string to date object:

```
data = []
with open(inputFile, "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        line = line.split(maxsplit=6)
        logdate = " ".join(line[:6])
        logstatus = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        loginfo = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        data.append({"LogDate": logdate, "LogStatus": logstatus, "LogInfo": loginfo})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["LogDate"] = df["LogDate"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, ignoretz=True)
```

However, for those lines that starts with another string (i.e. java.net.Socket...), other than date I am getting an error when it tries to parse since it cannot do it which is correct. How am I able to pass this? I would like that if the string can be parsed to do so, otherwise to ignore and do nothing. I've tried this but when it gets to the `except` block, it updates all the output file.

```
try:
    df["LogDate"] = df["LogDate"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, ignoretz=True)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

**Output file**

```
LogDate,LogStatus,LogInfo
"May 6, 2021 12:40:05 AM CEST",INFO,[com.purge.PurgeManager run] PURGE: Purge all data beginning (1 threads)
"May 6, 2021 9:12:17 AM CEST",FINE,[com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientCall sendRequest] An error occured during the communication with the remote HTTP server.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out,out,out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method),Method),Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116),java.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you will have a rough time parsing unstructured data and storing in a table.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: I need to process that file further, in a monitoring tool that accepts a specific range of timestamps as row delimiter.

Comment: Maybe you can try casting `logdate` to a datetime-like while you are reading the data and catch any exception and continue reading.

Comment: How your df looks before the parsing ?? You sure logdate is empty where there is no data ?

Comment: @pippo1980 - it looks as the sample provided. Some lines within the file, starts with a string date whereas others, start with `java.net.Socket...`.

Comment: I took a look.  This is a bad idea.  You should reconsider your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
months = (
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
)
data = []
with open(inputFile, "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        # Add a new condition
        if not line or not line.startswith(months):
            continue
        line = line.split(maxsplit=6)
        logdate = " ".join(line[:6])
        logstatus = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        loginfo = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        data.append({"LogDate": logdate, "LogStatus": logstatus, "LogInfo": loginfo})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["LogDate"] = df["LogDate"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, ignoretz=True)

print(df)
# Outputs
              LogDate LogStatus                                            LogInfo
0 2021-05-06 00:40:05      INFO  [com.purge.PurgeManager run] PURGE: Purge all ...
1 2021-05-06 09:12:17      FINE  [com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpClientCall sendR...
```